# iOS: Key-Value Observing does not dismiss modal view

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I have the following key value observer method in a modal view:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
  if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"uploadComplete"]) {
    NSLog(@"UploadVC hears upload complete");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  }
}
```

I use this to watch a photo object and know when it is finished uploading. When I run this it behaves as expected, and the console logs "UploadVC hears upload complete" - but then the following line is not executed -- the modal does not get dismissed.

There are no errors or anything else, the view just sits there and the modal is never dismissed. What's going on here?

Comment: Can you show the code that presents the view controller in question? It sounds like maybe it was pushed onto the nav stack instead of being presented modally.

Comment: It was presented modally, in the calling controller `[self presentViewController:uploadViewController animated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That may happen when you receive KVO notification on background thread and so attempts to update UI may result in any unexpected behaviour (UI not changed, changed after some delay, app crash etc etc). Make sure you call all updating UI code on main thread:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
  if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"uploadComplete"]) {
     NSLog(@"UploadVC hears upload complete");
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     });

  }
}
```

Comment: There we go. Follow up question: how do you know when a method is going to get called from a background thread? How can I anticipate this kind of behavior in the future? And - what is `dispatch_async`? Sorry I'm brand new to iOS! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Basically you if you can not be sure on which thread method can be called you should code "defensively" and make sure that you will update UI on main thread. dispatch_async is a method to execute block asynchronously on a arbitrary dispatch queue (here we use main queue which is basically the same as executing block on main thread). You can read more about all that here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html